# Function pointer with "not a type" error when using template in interface file

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, typedef

I am creating an interface file for my library with a method of passing a function pointer. There are 2 approaches:

A: Defined as a member function of a template class

B: Defined as a global

```cpp
// A:
template<typename T>
using fcnPtr1 = void (T::*)(const int&);

// B:
typedef void(*fcnPtr2)(const int&);

class TestInterface
{
public:
    // A: This cause error 'fcnPtr1' is not a type
    virtual void setCallback(fcnPtr1 callback) = 0;

    // B: This is OK
    virtual void setCallback(fcnPtr2 callback) = 0;
};
```

As of now, approach A gives me an error of "fcnPtr1" is not a type but approach B is ok.

I need to use approach A because don't want my client to define the callback function in global. Any advice?

Comment: As the error correctly says `fcnPtr1` is not a type. It is a template. `fcnPtr1<SomeType>` is a type. The difference between the two is that `fcnPtr1` could be a member function pointer of some arbitrary class while `fcnPtr2` is a free function pointer. They are different.

Answer (score 3):

In your code `fcnPtr1` is a template.  Since it is a template you need to provide the template type with it to actually instantiate it.  This basically undoes what you just did though so it's not helpful

If you need to take arbitray functions but and only want to control the signature then what you can use is a `std::function`.  By using a `std::function` parameter you can take any type of callable that has a matching function signature.  That would turn your code into

```
class TestInterface
{
public:
    virtual void setCallback(std::function<void(const int&)> callback) = 0;
};
```